# posting tweet is not working 

Tags: objective-c

i am creating an iPhone sample,there i have used Twitter API for authenticating the user and storing the response user credentials in database.Using the authToken from the twitter response i want to autotweet time to time. I am successfull in autotweeting.but Actually i created a ON/OFF switch.if switch is on it tweets automatically time to time...i am able to auto tweet as an independent sample or call from some class,but when i am trying to call from switch button values..it is not working.It is calling the API Successfully But not PostingSome one plz help.

Comment: You need to paste some code for people to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter never allows duplicate tweets to be posted.So, please make sure that whether each & every you are trying to send is same or not.

Otherwise try this:

```
[_engine sendUpdate:[NSString stringwithFormat:@"The date & time is: %@",[NSDate date]]];
```